# Laravel 5 - Conditionally resolve service provider

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I have a set of concrete implementations for a base class `ProductChecker` and I'm looking for the most "idiomatic" way to resolve the correct implementation from my controller class.

My controller has a method as follows:

```
public function check_product($subid, $prod_id){
    $sub = Subcategory::where("subid","=",$subid)->first();
    $checker = //// How do I resolve the correct implementation here ? 
    return response()->json($checker->check_product($prod_id));
}
```

I know about the IoC container but it sounds like a lot of boilerplate to me, having to bind each class to a string value (making it error prone ?) and resolving by that same string value (error prone ?).

Coming form .NET, I thought of defining metadata on my implementation class that references `Subcategory` and then resolving it. But it sounded too hack-y and I didn't have much luck with it.

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying hard to understand your question. Is it possible you explain a little more in simple terms what you want to do. On a side note, I appreciate your technical tone but I think I can help. Okay if I can guess, generally when you pass that class in the constructor of the controller `public function __construct(ProductChecker $pc){ $this->pc = $pc;....}` then you can use it in your method as `$this->pc`. Let me know if I got you wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I perhaps mis-phrased my inquiry. I was indeed, as stated by @Thomas looking for contextual binding: having different implementations of the same interface based on a condition. However what Thomas suggested assumes that I'm constructing another class with that dependency, whereas I'm calling from a function as stated in my code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#contextual-binding)

The example looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Http\Controllers\PhotoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\VideoController;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;

$this->app->when(PhotoController::class)
          ->needs(Filesystem::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return Storage::disk('local');
          });

$this->app->when([VideoController::class, UploadController::class])
          ->needs(Filesystem::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return Storage::disk('s3');
          });
```

What you should do is let the classes implement the same `Checker` interface. 
As for

> having to bind each class to a string value (making it error prone ?)

You can use the class constant (e.g. `Filesystem::class`) to not have to use strings to reference class and namespace.

> Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name
>   resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name
>   of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly
>   useful with namespaced classes.

Comment: This is indeed close to what I need, thank you. However, I'm not trying to construct a new class with that dependency, instead I'm trying to just resolve the correct implementation based on a condition on the `$sub` variable. For instance: `if($sub->id == 3) return NewFirstChecker(); else return new OtherChecker`, but in a more elegant way. Thanks.